# Node.js - Express / upload image using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

In an express 3 app, I have a simple file upload form used to submit an image using ajax and Formidable.

In my version of express, Formidable is included in Connect middleware.

When I process the file upload, only one part of the image is uploaded BUT the weight is more important.

Example :

the base image with a weight of **74Ko**

[image: base image]

the uploaded image after process has a weight of **90ko** and is not fully loaded as you can see

[image: uploaded image]

The process's behavior is strange when I want to parse the form in my post route, it seems the image was parsed 2 times

Here is the js code

```
if(document.addEventListener) {
    document.getElementById("upload_event_image").addEventListener("change", function(e){
        uploadImages(e);
    });
}
else {
    document.getElementById("upload_event_image").attachEvent("onchange", function(e){
        uploadImages(e);
    });
}

function uploadImages(e) {

    var formData = new FormData();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //xhr.dataType = 'json';

    var onReady = function(e) {

        if(this.readyState == this.DONE) {

            if(this.status != 200) {

                console.log('An error occured with the file upload');

            } else {

                var returnedData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                if(returnedData.response == 'success') {

                    console.log('File uploaded : ' + returnedData.image_name);

                }

            }

        }

    };

    var onError = function(err) {
        // something went wrong with upload
        console.log('Upload error : ' + err);
    };

    formData.append('data', e.target.files[0]);

    xhr.open('post', "/markers/upload_event_image", true);
    xhr.addEventListener('error', onError, false);
    xhr.send(formData);
    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', onReady, false);

}
```

and the route

```
router.post('/markers/upload_event_image', express.bodyParser({defer: true}), function (req, res) {
    var form = req.form;

    form.encoding = 'binary';
    form.uploadDir = __dirname + '/client/tmp';
    form.maxFieldsSize = 50 * 1024 * 1024;
    form.keepExtensions = true;

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {

        if (err) return console.log(err); 

    });
});
```

Another think, if I use `form.on('file', function(name, file) { ... });` instead of `form.parse...`, it works great !